# Discord bot responds to commands in DMs but not in server channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created a Discord bot using Python and the discord.py library. My bot is supposed to respond to a !ping command with pong. It works correctly when I send the command in a direct message to the bot, but it does not respond when I use the command in a server channel.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
intents.messages = True

TOKEN = 'my-token'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command(name='ping', help='This command returns pong')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I have given the bot all necessary permissions on the server (including administrator permissions). I've also made sure that the bot is not muted or restricted in the server channels where I'm testing the command. The bot is online and visible in the server. However, it still only responds to the !ping command in a direct message, and not in any server channels.

The output log doesn't show any errors. The bot connects to the Discord Gateway and logs in using the static token, but there's no response when I use the !ping command in the server.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

These are the Intents:
[image]

These are the authorisations:
[image]

I tried tinkering with the code adding more intention instances.

I also made the bot's role as Admin:
[image]

I made sure the Permission to send messages was ticked:
[image]

I tried kicking it out and inviting it back in a bunch of times, while trying diverse combinations.

Me trying in the server:
[image]

Me trying in dm:
[image]

The command line:
[image]

What the code looks like at the moment:
[image]

EDIT/UPDATE:

I changed the code (thanks to a user in the comments) as follows and it works!

````
intents.typing = True
intents.presences = True
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76460301/14797384

Comment: Hi, nope, I stumbled across that question too and I did add "message_content", but, unless I messed up the order of definition, it's not doing anything different

Comment: I think the order might be it, you are overwriting your intents 3 times in total. If you just delete the duplicate lines that say `intents = discord.Intents.default()` it might work (Keep the top one). On another note, you should definitely delete the screenshot with your bot token by the way, and regenerate it ASAP!

Comment: I'll try your solution soon, thanks for that! And I re-generated the token as soon as I posted this question, but I can definitely see this as a potential mistake, cheers mate!

Comment: So I updated the code as follows (below) and it worked:

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = True
intents.presences = True
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

Thank you so much! A trivial problem, but I've been stuck on this for a while nonetheless so thanks again mate!